# Installing Unity shell on Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ubuntu-unity

ref: http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/#build-nux

While trying to install the build dependencies, I get:
"E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list"

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The guide is for Ubuntu. Mint is Ubuntu derivate, but is using different commands, as you can see for example from the [official guide](http://www.linuxmint.com/documentation/user-guide/Cinnamon/english_17.2.pdf):

> Open the menu and select “Terminal”. Then type the following command:
>
> ```
> apt install opera
> ```

So therefore you should do

```
sudo apt build-dep nux
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nux
```

and so on. But note, that the guide might differ further and you might not be even able to install Unity on Mint because of some differences.